# is it possible to continue using flutter SDK "1.20.0" and not upgrading anymore? any future problems can arise from that behavior?

Tags: flutter, dart

every time i get a notification to upgrade to newer flutter SDK and i do the upgrade...my project gets broken...due to incompatibility of packages with each others...i tried to install the packages again one by one...also tried to manipulate the packages version...i tried to migrate to different flutter channels like master, dev, beta..going back to stable...but no luck :(

and i end up in downgrading the flutter SDK to "1.20.0" again...i did that everytime till the newest version of flutter SDK "1.22.4 1aafb3a 13/11/2020"

once i downgrade to "1.20.0"..everything goes fine...

for example...one of the errors am facing right now using the flutter SDK "1.22.4"..when i flutter pub get..i get this:

```
Because every version of flutter_common_exports depends on flutter_localizations any from sdk which depends on collection 1.15.0-nullsafety.3, every version of flutter_common_exports requires collection 1.15.0-nullsafety.3.

And because dartx >=0.2.0 <0.5.0 depends on collection >=1.14.11 <1.15.0, flutter_common_exports is incompatible with dartx >=0.2.0 <0.5.0.

So, because myApp depends on flutter_common_exports any which depends on dartx ^0.4.1, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because myApp depends on flutter_common_exports any which depends on dartx ^0.4.1, version solving failed.)
exit code 1
```

am using:

`Flutter 1.22.4 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git`

`Framework • revision 1aafb3a8b9 (28 hours ago) • 2020-11-13 09:59:28 -0800`

`Engine • revision 2c956a31c0`

`Tools • Dart 2.10.4`

so what will happen if i didn't follow any upgrade notifications and continue developing my app using flutter SDK "1.20.0" till i release my app to the store ?!

is there any consequences that will happen?!

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, you can’t use the latest SDK on this project yet, not while the packages you’re using don’t get updated and are compatible with the latest SDK.

You can use the old SDK, you're just missing out on new features.

If you work with a team, you should start declaring the compatible SDK on your “pubspec.yaml” file, so that everyone knows which SDK version it was tested for:

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.2.2 <3.0.0"
  flutter: "1.9.1+hotfix.6"
```