# Flutter in VSCode is not connecting to devtools

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

i am using flutter:

Flutter 1.20.0 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 840c9205b3 (6 months ago) • 2020-08-04 20:55:12 -0700
Engine • revision c8e3b94853
Tools • Dart 2.9.0

the main reason i am still using Flutter 1.20.0 is my own question i asked here also:

[is it possible to continue using flutter SDK "1.20.0" and not upgrading anymore? any future problems can arise from that behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64839257/is-it-possible-to-continue-using-flutter-sdk-1-20-0-and-not-upgrading-anymore)

till yesterday everything was working well...today i am trying to open devtools in VScode but i keep getting this:

[VScode cannot connect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtZiR.png)

i tried:

`flutter pub global deactivate devtools`

`flutter pub global activate devtools`

`flutter pub global run devtools`

but nothing changes

i tried:

`flutter pub cache repair`

it reinstalled all my project packages....

and i tried

`pub clean` it deleted all previous builds

when i try to run App with `flutter run --observatory-port=9200`

and i take the URL from the logcat and paste it in the devtools to connect to the current working App..i get this:

[chrome devtools cannot connect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vuci.png)

i am able to run devtools in Android studio successfully with Flutter Inspector...why i am not able to use devtools in VScode!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug in a recent release of DevTools that didn't gracefully handle versions of Flutter that were missing a new API:

https://github.com/flutter/devtools/issues/2648

This bug was fixed in version `0.9.7+2` of DevTools, which VS Code should automatically update to. If it doesn't, you can manually update with:

```
pub global activate devtools
```

Note: do not include a `flutter`  prefix.

If `pub` isn't in your `PATH` you may need to run it with a full path like:

```
(flutter SDK)\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\pub global activate devtools
```

Comment: on windows use flutter pub command instead as pub is integrated part of flutter

Comment: On the latest version DevTools is part of the SDK and you shouldn't use the version from Pub at all :)